# Data type checking while coding a customization

Tags: acumatica

Tl;dr - **How do you check the data type of an object while coding?** Is there a debug console?
I've been using "throw new PXException" to troubleshoot my code.

```
throw new PXException(String.Format("Hello World. Please see the below contents. \nOwnedFilterExt.UsrPGDate = {0} \n Base.Activity.Date = {1}", ownedFilterExt.UsrPGDate, Base.Activity.Date));
```

Please excuse this Acumatica noob question. My background is primarily in console applications and backend scripts. This simple question comes to mind as I code more complex customizations progressively for Acumatica.

Edit1: I am more concerned with whole "row sets" or "filter" objects commonly called in the Graphs. If I access/modify them, I want to track the transformation of the data.

Any feedback is helpful. Even if you just point me to some help articles.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but if you hit F12 when the cursor is on UsrPGDate in visual studio, it will drill down to that class/property etc and you can check its type.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It has been on my "to-do" list to get Acuminator working. I'm not concerned with UsrPGDate (except for observing its data transformation). 

I am more concerned with whole "row sets" or "filter" objects that are commonly called in the Graphs. If I access/modify them, I want to track the transformation of the data.

Comment: Maybe this could help, place a few breakpoints in the graph event code, and then look at the Caches of the graph, look for the DAC row type in the collection and then look at the "Inserted" updated and deleted collections within the cache.

Comment: Additionally, you can use PXTrace.WriteInformation("value"); to write logs to the trace without an exception

Comment: Awesome! this sounds perfect. I can't wait to try that this week.
Thanks, Kyle!